# How to separate two scanfs between two different programs?

Tags: c

So i have two programs. One turns typed symbols into ASCII number(or hexo number if im coorect) and other calculates percentage of typed number. The problems is it asks to type in symbol and number right at the start. I wanna make it separated so i have to write firstly some symbol, program shows me text and then i write number do it will show me percentage of it.

I can't share the code because i have no PC or laptop so im programing everything on my phone and it wont share the code correctly :(

Comment: Make at least a screenshot please.

Comment: ASCII is a one-byte encoding; perhaps a 256-bin histogram?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and it is difficult since you have described the problem very badly and with poor grammar. You should save all the ASCII symbols into an array. Once this is done you can save all numbers in another array. You can do it like this:

```
int i;
printf("How many symbols do you want to insert?\n");

if(scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char* a = malloc(i * sizeof(char));
if(a == NULL) {
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  if(scanf("%c", &a[i]) != 1) {
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

printf("How many numbers do you want to insert?\n");

if(scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int* n = malloc(i * sizeof(int));
if(n == NULL) {
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  if(scanf("%d", &n[i]) != 1) {
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

Now you have an array `a` with all your symbols and an array `n` with all your numbers and you can iterate on the arrays to do what you want with the informations saved.

Comment: 1. Please use braces - do not want to get with your trousers down. 2. `scanf` returns a value - this should be checked

Comment: Done, tell me if now is ok, thank you for you advices!

Comment: I think i did. Can i ask you why someone tells that braces is wrong and someone that is right? (obviously when i can omit them). Thank you.

Comment: Always put then in. It prevents  confusion, makes the code more readable and prevents silly errors.